# Convert Xcode Project to Android Through Unity

Tags: android, xcode, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to take my natively built Xcode iOS project and use Unity to generate an Android project?

Comment: No. You generate the Android project from Unity

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the answer will be no, because Unity can only "convert" his progect for multiple platforms, an XCode project can't be converted using Unity, The same applies to an Android project that can't be converted using unity.